# Matching indices of arrays of different sizes

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, indexing, combinations

Let's say we have a **DATA** array consisting of 23 elements,
And **INDICATORS** array of 3 elements (might be whatever size you want: 3, 5, 7 etc but less then *DATA* array)

Let's say I'm iterating over **DATA** array, and starting from, say, index 4 in the **DATA** array, I need to start highlighting **INDICATORS** one by one, starting from the first, then second, then third and then wrapping back to the first.

For example:

**DATA** indexes:0...(4, 5, 6) (7, 8, 9)...22

**INDICATORS** indexes: (0, 1, 2) (0, 1, 2) ... etc

So basically I need to convert index 4 of **DATA** array to index 0 of the **INDICATORS** array, index 5 of **DATA** array to index 1 of the **INDICATORS** array etc.

dataArrayIndex % indicatorsArraySize doesn't work in this case.

How do I do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: @JackBashford I'd prefer not to attach to any language or framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataArrayIndex % indicatorsArraySize
```

Won't work for you because you have that starting index.

Instead, you have to subtract your starting index from the `dataArrayIndex` first:

```
(dataArrayIndex - dataStartIndex) % indicatorsArraySize
```

---

Alternatively, as you iterate, you can compare your current `indicatorsArrayIndex` to `indicatorsArraySize`, after incrementing `indicatorsArrayIndex`. If they're equal, reset `indicatorsArrayIndex` to 0.

Comment: Your first solution is perfect. Thank you Thomas, you saved my day!